# InfluxDB with docker permission denied .influx_history

Tags: docker, docker-compose, influxdb

I tried to setup InfluxDB with docker. This worked fine so far but entering the cli I get the error

```
There was an error writing history file: open /.influx_history: permission denied
```

Afer every command execution. Creating a database worked so far.

The part of my docker-compose file:

```
  influxdb:
    image: influxdb
    container_name: influxdb
    logging:
      options:
        max-size: "10m"
        max-file: "5"
    ports:
      - 8086:8086
    volumes:
      - /Users/XXX/docker-data/influxdb:/var/lib/influxdb:z
      - /Users/XXX/docker-data/influxdb/.influx_history:/.influx_history
    user: "501:20"
    restart: always
```

I tried to map the file directly but still it not works.

Any idea on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems user `501:20` doesn't have read permissions over file: `/.influx_history`

There're many ways to solve it

you can either change the write permissions at host level `chmox a+w /Users/XXX/docker-data/influxdb/.influx_history`

or change ownership to user `501` and/or group `20` by doing `chown 501:20 /Users/XXX/docker-data/influxdb/.influx_history`

Comment: thanks adjusting the user in and outside fixed the issue

Comment: In my specific case i had the influx data on `/var/lib/influxdb/`, so I needed to create the `.influx_history` file there. Next I did `sudo chown influxdb:influxdb /var/lib/influxdb/.influx_history` and then I ran the docker influxdb container attaching a volume like this: `-v /var/lib/influxdb/.influx_history:/.influx_history`. The message `There was an error writing history file: open /.influx_history: permission denied` desappear.